# Усыпить поток делегированием метода

Tags: java, многопоточность, методы, concurrency

Добрый день!
вот код:

```
public class A extends Thread
{
A otherThread = null; 
Integer i = null;

public A(Integer i)
{
    this.i = i;
}

public A(A t, Integer i)
{
    this.i = i;
    otherThread = t;
}

public void makeMeSleep() throws InterruptedException
{
    Thread.sleep(33000);
}

public void makeOtherThSleep()
{
    if(otherThread != null)
    {
        try {
            otherThread.makeMeSleep();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    try {
        this.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
    while(true)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

public static void main(String argv[]) throws InterruptedException
{
    A th1 = new A(1);
    A th2 = new A(th1, 5);
    th1.start();
    th2.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    th2.makeOtherThSleep();
}

  }
```

Я хочу усыпить другой поток, но он сопротивляется. Я знаю что метод статический и каждый поток сам его может вызвать, объекты снаружи не могут его усыпить, кроме....делегирования! Но почему-то все равно не работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поток должен усылять себя самостоятельно. Попытки усыпить из другого треда в большинстве случаев приводят к печали - он может остановиться в произвольном месте.

Правильный способ заключается в том, что вызывающий тред должен выставить переменную-флажок (это может быть поле класса, к примеру). А тред, который должен заснуть, время от времени проверяет ее и если он готов - засыпает.

Пример из реальной жизни. Для того, что бы уложить спать человека, Вы ведь не бьете его дубинкой по голове? а просто просите.

Вернемся к java. В большинстве случаев подобное усыпление не нужно. Человечество изобрело примитивы синхронизации. Вам скорее всего подойдет "ожидание". Примеры - [Java Thread: notify() and wait() examples](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/notify-and-wait-example/).

Comment: PS Я смог усыпить поток делегированием. Но для этого надо было вытащить **run()** из конструктора.

Comment: главное, что бы свой же поток не усыпили:) Покажите код.

Comment: а, собственно сверху и есть рабочий вариант.))

Comment: Интересно, а зачем так сложно?

Разве нельзя прямо в `main` вместо `th2.makeOtherThSleep();` прямо вызвать `th1.sleep(33000)` ?

--

Пардон (посмотрел доку), действительно нельзя

     static void  sleep(long millis) 

есть только статический метод.

--

Собственно, можно прямо из `main` вызывать `th1.makeMeSleep()`, но видимо это очевидно и поэтому не интересно.

А вот, что интересно, так это вызвать `th1.makeMeSleep()` **после** `th2.makeOtherThSleep()` в `main` и посмотреть, уснет ли `main` на этом вызове.

Comment: вот как раз тот тред, который, пусть даже такими путями, вызвал sleep, заснет. И в этом случае - это будет main. Проверить это очень просто. Нужно после `th2.makeOtherThSleep();` добавить такое.

     System.out.println("After Other thread Sleep");
     th2.join();
     th1.join();

Судя по логике, сообщение должно быть вызвано сразу. А оно будет только через 33 секунды.

Comment: @KoVadim, т.о. Ваш ответ видимо надо модифицировать, явно сказав, что *sleep всегда усыпляет поток, вызвавший sleep*, независимо от того какими путями (вызовом каких методов) по классам 

(и даже независимо от того, каким потоком создавались эти экземпляры классов)

он дошел до этого вызова.

Comment: я бы не был так категоричен. Найдется хитрец, который так выкрутит, что sleep будет усыплять какой-то третий поток.